# How to retrieve older form data before updating it to new one using NodeJS, Express and mongodb! Ejs is the template?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, ejs

I need to retrieve all older data of a form, before updating it to new one. I need those form data for a reporting purpose. It basically will be the version of a data.

I am working on #Nodejs #ExpressJS #EJS as template and #MONGODB,#mongoose.

Below are the images of the code! I am new to the programming so please help me with the coding part not describe it using coding Jargans!

1. Schema Snippet

```js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bcrypt   = require('bcrypt-nodejs');

// define the schema for our user model
var procedureschema = mongoose.Schema({
  proceduretype : String,
  procedurename : String,
  procedurenumber : String,
  scope : String,
  status:{type:String,lowercase:true,enum:["draft", "active", "pending"]},
  forms : String,
  relatedprocedure : String,
  norms : String,
  qualityrecords : String,
  expdate : String,
  companyname : String,
  version : String,
  owner: String,
  approver : String,
  procedurefiles : String,
  flowchart : String,
  proceduredescription : String,
  isotags : String,
  departmentname : String
});

// generating a password hash



// create the model for users and expose it to our app
module.exports = mongoose.model('Procedure', procedureschema);
```

2. Form view EJS page

```html
<% include sidebar.ejs %>

<div class="dt-content">

  <!-- Page Header -->
  <!-- <div class="dt-page__header">
    <h1 class="dt-page__title">New Procedure</h1>
  </div> -->
  <!--  /page header -->



  <!-- Grid -->
  <div class="row">
    <!-- Grid Item -->
    <div class="col-xl-12">

      <!-- Card -->
      <div class="dt-card">

          <div class="dt-card__header">
  
              <!-- Card Heading -->
              <div class="dt-card__heading">
                <h3 class="dt-card__title">New Procedure</h3>
              </div>
              <!-- /card heading -->
                  <a type="button" href="/admin/add/procedure/forms" role="button" class="btn btn-dark mr-2 mb-2"> Add Forms</a>                  
                  <a type="button" href="/admin/add/procedure/type" role="button" class="btn btn-dark mr-2 mb-2"> Add Procedure Type</a>
                  <a type="button" href="/admin/add/procedure/norms" role="button" class="btn btn-dark mr-2 mb-2"> Add Norms</a>
                  <a type="button" href="/admin/add/procedure/tags" role="button" class="btn btn-dark mr-2 mb-2"> Add Procedure Tags</a>
    
            </div>

        <!-- Card Header -->
      
        <!-- /card header -->
        <div class="dt-card__body">
          <form action="/admin/create/procedure" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="form-row">
              <div class="col-sm-6 mb-3">
                <label>Procedure Type</label>
                <div class="input-group">
                  <select class="custom-select" name="proceduretype" id="inputGroupSelect04">
                    <option selected>Choose Procedure Type</option>
                    <% procedurecat.forEach(function(data){%>
                    <option value="<%=data.category_name %>"><%=data.category_name %></option>
                    <%})%>
                  </select>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="col-sm-6 mb-3">
                <label>Procedure Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationDefault03" name="procedurename" placeholder="Enter Procedure Name"
                  required>
              </div>

              <div class="col-sm-6 mb-3">
                <label>Procedure Number</label>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" name="procedurenumber"  id="validationDefault03" placeholder="Enter Procedure Number"
                  required>
              </div>

              <div class="col-sm-6 mb-3">
                <label>Scope</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationDefault03" name="scope" placeholder="Enater Procedure Scope"
                  required>
              </div>

              <div class="col-sm-6 mb-3">
                <label>Status</label>
                <div class="input-group">
                  <select class="custom-select" name="status" id="inputGroupSelect04">
                    <option selected>Choose Status</option>
                    <option value="draft">Draft</option>
                    <option value="pending">Pending</option>
                    <option value="active">Active</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="col-sm-6 mb-3">
                <label>Forms</label>
                <div class="input-group">
                  <select class="custom-select" name="forms" id="inputGroupSelect04">
                    <option selected>Choose Forms</option>
                    <% forms.forEach(function(data){%>
                      <option value="<%=data.forms_name %>"><%=data.forms_name %></option>
                      <%})%>
                  </select>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="col-sm-6 mb-3">
                <label>Related Procedure</label>
                <div class="input-group">
                  <select class="custom-select" name="relatedprocedure" id="inputGroupSelect04">
                    <option selected>Choose Related Procedures</option>
                    <% proceduretitle.forEach(function(data){%>
                      <option value="<%=data.procedurename %>"><%=data.procedurename %></option>
                      <%})%>
                  </select>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="col-sm-6 mb-3">
                <label>Select Norms</label>
                <div class="input-group">
                  <select class="custom-select" name="norms" id="inputGroupSelect04">
                    <option selected>Choose Norms</option>
                    <% norms.forEach(function(data){%>
                      <option value="<%=data.norms_name %>"><%=data.norms_name %></option>
                      <%})%>
                  </select>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="col-sm-6 mb-3">
                <label>Quality Records</label>
                <input type="text" name="qualityrecords" class="form-control" id="validationDefault03"
                  placeholder="Enter Quality Records Here" required>
              </div>

              <div class="col-sm-6 mb-3">
                <label>Expiration Date</label>
                <div class="input-group date" id="date-time-picker-1" data-target-input="nearest">
                  <input type="text" name = "expdate" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" data-target="#date-time-picker-1" />
                  <div class="input-group-append" data-target="#date-time-picker-1" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
                    <div class="input-group-text"><i class="icon icon-calendar"></i></div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="col-sm-6 mb-3">
                  <label>Company Name</label>
                  <input type="text" value="<%= user.companyname %>" name="companyname" class="form-control" id="validationDefault03" readonly
                   >
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-6 mb-3">
                    <label>Version</label>
                    <input type="number" step ="0.1" name="version" class="form-control" id="validationDefault03" placeholder="Auto Increased field"
                      required>
                  </div>

              <div class="col-sm-6 mb-3">
                <label>Owner</label>
                <div class="input-group">
                  <select class="custom-select" name="owner" id="inputGroupSelect04">
                    <option selected>Choose Owner</option>
                    <% users.forEach(function(data){%>
                      <option value="<%=data.name %>"><%=data.name %></option>
                      <%})%>
                  </select>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="col-sm-6 mb-3">
                <label>Approver</label>
                <div class="input-group">
                  <select class="custom-select" name="approver" id="inputGroupSelect04">
                    <option selected>Choose Approver</option>
                    <% users.forEach(function(data){%>
                      <option value="<%=data.name %>"><%=data.name %></option>
                      <%})%>
                  </select>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="col-sm-6 mb-3">
                <label>Departmnent Name</label>
                <div class="input-group">
                  <select class="custom-select" name="departmentname" id="inputGroupSelect04">
                    <option selected>Choose Department Name</option>
                    <% department.forEach(function(data){%>
                      <option value="<%=data.departmentname %>"><%=data.departmentname %></option>
                      <%})%>
                  </select>
                </div>
              </div>

              

              <div class="col-sm-12 mb-3 form-row">
                <label class=" col-form-label text-sm-left" for="file-field">Attached Files</label>

                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-9">
                  <div class="custom-file">
                    <input type="file" name="procedurefiles" onchange="GetFileSizeNameAndType()" id="file" class="custom-file-input" id="file-field" multiple>
                    <label class="custom-file-label" for="file-field">Attacthed your files here ..</label>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-row input-group">
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 form-row">
                        <div id="fp"></div>
                      
                    </div>
                  </div>
              </div>


              

              <div class=" col-sm-12 mb-4 ">
                  <label class=" text-sm-left mb-4">Flowchart</label>
                <button type="button" href="javascript:void(0)" role="button" class="btn btn-dark mr-2 mb-2">Design your flowchart</button>
              </div>

              <div class=" col-sm-12 mb-4 ">
                  <label>Description</label>
              <textarea class=" col-sm-12 mb-4" name="proceduredescription" id="summernote"></textarea>
                  
        
                
                </div>
          

            </div>

            <hr class="border-dashed my-8">

            <div class=" form-row mb-4 ">
              <label class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 text-sm-right mb-4 mb-sm-0">Read Confirmation</label>
              <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-9">

                <!-- Checkbox -->
                <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox custom-control-inline">
                  <input type="checkbox" id="customcheckboxInline1" name="customcheckboxInline1"
                    class="custom-control-input" checked>
                  <label class="custom-control-label" for="customcheckboxInline1"></label>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          

            <hr class="border-dashed my-8">

            <div class="form-group form-row mb-0 col-md-12">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary text-uppercase">Submit this procedure</button>
            </div>

            


          </form>
        </div>
        <!-- Card Body -->


      </div>
      <!-- /card body -->

    </div>
    <!-- /card -->

  </div>
  <!-- /grid item -->

</div>
<!-- /grid -->


<!-- /site content -->


<% include footer.ejs %>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#summernote').summernote();
  });</script>

<script>
    function GetFileSizeNameAndType()
{
var fi = document.getElementById('file'); // GET THE FILE INPUT AS VARIABLE.

var totalFileSize = 0;

// VALIDATE OR CHECK IF ANY FILE IS SELECTED.
if (fi.files.length > 0)
{
    // RUN A LOOP TO CHECK EACH SELECTED FILE.
    for (var i = 0; i <= fi.files.length - 1; i++)
    {
        //ACCESS THE SIZE PROPERTY OF THE ITEM OBJECT IN FILES COLLECTION. IN THIS WAY ALSO GET OTHER PROPERTIES LIKE FILENAME AND FILETYPE
        var fsize = fi.files.item(i).size;
        totalFileSize = totalFileSize + fsize;
        
        document.getElementById('fp').innerHTML = document.getElementById('fp').innerHTML + '<br /> ' + 'File Name is <b>' + fi.files.item(i).name + "</b>.";
    }
}
document.getElementById('divTotalSize').innerHTML = "Total File(s) Size is <b>" + Math.round(totalFileSize / 1024) + "</b> KB";
}
</script>
```

3. Routes of that form Post and Update API

```js
app.post('/create/procedure', function (req, res) {
  
  let proceduresinglefiles = req.files.procedurefiles
  if(Array.isArray(proceduresinglefiles)==false){
  console.log(Array.isArray(proceduresinglefiles));
  console.log(typeof(proceduresinglefiles));
  console.log(proceduresinglefiles);
  var filename = proceduresinglefiles.name;
  proceduresinglefiles.mv('./public/assets/documents/procedure/' + filename, function(err) {
   if (err)
   console.log(err);
});

  var procedure = Procedure();

  procedure.proceduretype = req.body.proceduretype;
  procedure.procedurename = req.body.procedurename;
  procedure.procedurenumber = req.body.procedurenumber;
  procedure.scope = req.body.scope;
  procedure.status = req.body.status;
  procedure.forms = req.body.forms;
  procedure.relatedprocedure = req.body.relatedprocedure;
  procedure.norms = req.body.norms;
  procedure.qualityrecords = req.body.qualityrecords;
  procedure.expdate = req.body.expdate;
  procedure.companyname = req.body.companyname;
  procedure.version = req.body.version;
  procedure.owner = req.body.owner;
  procedure.approver = req.body.approver;
  procedure.procedurefiles = filename;
  procedure.flowchart = req.body.flowchart;
  procedure.proceduredescription = req.body.proceduredescription;
  procedure.isotags = req.body.isotags;
  procedure.departmentname = req.body.departmentname

  procedure.save(function (err, getprocedure) {
    if (err) res.json(err);

    else {
      console.log(getprocedure);
      res.redirect("/admin/view/procedure");
    }

  })
}

else
     {
      
      var filenamea=[];
      for(var i=0;i<proceduresinglefiles.length;i++){
        console.log(proceduresinglefiles.length);
        console.log(i);
        
      var procedurefilename = proceduresinglefiles[i].name;
      console.log(procedurefilename);
      filenamea[i]=procedurefilename;
      console.log(filenamea);
      proceduresinglefiles[i].mv('./public/assets/documents/procedure/' + procedurefilename, function(err) {

        if (err)
         console.log(err);
      });
      
      }
      
    
    let multipleprocedurefilename= filenamea.toString();
    var procedure = Procedure();

  procedure.proceduretype = req.body.proceduretype;
  procedure.procedurename = req.body.procedurename;
  procedure.procedurenumber = req.body.procedurenumber;
  procedure.scope = req.body.scope;
  procedure.status = req.body.status;
  procedure.forms = req.body.forms;
  procedure.relatedprocedure = req.body.relatedprocedure;
  procedure.norms = req.body.norms;
  procedure.qualityrecords = req.body.qualityrecords;
  procedure.expdate = req.body.expdate;
  procedure.companyname = req.body.companyname;
  procedure.version = req.body.version;
  procedure.owner = req.body.owner;
  procedure.approver = req.body.approver;
  procedure.procedurefiles = multipleprocedurefilename;
  procedure.flowchart = req.body.flowchart;
  procedure.proceduredescription = req.body.proceduredescription;
  procedure.isotags = req.body.isotags;
  procedure.departmentname = req.body.departmentname

  procedure.save(function (err, getprocedure) {
    if (err) res.json(err);

    else {
      console.log(getprocedure);
      res.redirect("/admin/view/procedure");
    }

  })
}
});
```

```js
app.post('/edit/procedure/:id',(req, res) => {
  Procedure.findOneAndUpdate({_id:req.params.id},{
    $set:{

              proceduretype : req.body.proceduretype,
              procedurename : req.body.procedurename,
              procedurenumber : req.body.procedurenumber,
              scope : req.body.scope,
              status : req.body.status,
              forms : req.body.forms,
              relatedprocedure : req.body.relatedprocedure,
              norms : req.body.norms,
              qualityrecords : req.body.qualityrecords,
              expdate : req.body.expdate,
              companyname : req.body.companyname,
              version : req.body.version,
              owner : req.body.owner,
              approver : req.body.approver,
              procedurefiles : req.body.procedurefiles,
              flowchart : req.body.flowchart,
              proceduredescription : req.body.proceduredescription,
              isotags : req.body.isotags,
              departmentname : req.body.departmentname
  }}, 
  {new: true, upsert:true},
  function(err, procedurenew){
    if(err){
      console.log(err);
    }
    else
    {
      console.log(procedurenew);
      res.redirect('/admin/view/procedure')
    }
  }
  )
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand your problem, you need the old data before updating it to new one?
So you need to change(new:false) in your query API and your API code looks like:

```
app.post('/edit/procedure/:id',(req, res) => {
  Procedure.findOneAndUpdate({_id:req.params.id},{
    $set:{

              proceduretype : req.body.proceduretype,
              procedurename : req.body.procedurename,
              procedurenumber : req.body.procedurenumber,
              scope : req.body.scope,
              status : req.body.status,
              forms : req.body.forms,
              relatedprocedure : req.body.relatedprocedure,
              norms : req.body.norms,
              qualityrecords : req.body.qualityrecords,
              expdate : req.body.expdate,
              companyname : req.body.companyname,
              version : req.body.version,
              owner : req.body.owner,
              approver : req.body.approver,
              procedurefiles : req.body.procedurefiles,
              flowchart : req.body.flowchart,
              proceduredescription : req.body.proceduredescription,
              isotags : req.body.isotags,
              departmentname : req.body.departmentname
  }}, 
  {new: false, upsert:true},
  function(err, procedurenew){
    if(err){
      console.log(err);
    }
    else
    {
      console.log(procedurenew);
      res.redirect('/admin/view/procedure')
    }
  }
  )
});
```

[DO VOTE TO THIS ANSWER, IF ITS HELPFUL TO YOU]

Comment: Bro! I really appreciate your response! but I need it for reporting purpose! means the older data also save into the data and view on the view page. the new data as well as an older data!